# Object getting shared in Parallel.Foreach() Task Parallel Library

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a Parallel.Foreach() loop which will do business processing for each object in the collection. In the loop, i am creating new collections, adding new objects to collection. Parallel.Foreach loop will run periodically i.e. it is an windows service which will be always doing some business processing on the data.

Now the issue is some of the objects which are created in the previous execution are available for the next execution or some how the objects are shared which should not happen. Any ideas??

Comment: When you post some code we can tell you where/how you are using a capture variable the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question, you need to serialize your objects to a file and read them later, when you start next executions.

Comment: Simone, Thanks for u r response. By the time next execution starts previous step should be completed and all the objects must be disposed and Parallel.Foreach is a blocking execution which will wait till all the threads finish off its execution.